# NSJSONSerialization Fails to Parse Valid JSON - "Garbage at End"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sockets

My iOS program is receiving JSON data and trying to parse it but always fails for some reason I cannot determine. Multiple threads are calling this function almost at the same time. This only started happening once I switched to using GCDAsyncSocket, strangely. Here is the relevant code for receiving and parsing data:

```
// Called whenever I want my program to receive null-terminated data from the server:
[socket readDataToData:[NSData dataWithBytes:"\0" length:1] withTimeout:10 tag:0];

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag{ // a GCDAsyncSocket delegate method
    [self didReceiveNetworkData:data];
}

- (void)didReceiveNetworkData: (NSData*) data{
    if (TESTING) NSLog(@"Received network data of length %lu===\n%@\n===", (unsigned long) data.length, [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData: data
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
    if (!json){
        NSLog(@"Got an error parsing received JSON data: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    // Then I handle the dictionary (omitted code)…
}
```

The log and breakpoint debugger say that this is the data received:

```
{
"responseType": -1
}
```

To be exact, its bytes are "{\n\t\"responseType\":\t-1\n}\0". And I get this "garbage at end" error once the JSONObjectWithData function runs:

```
Got an error parsing received JSON data: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x10b203800 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
```

According to online JSON testers and my own simple test in a separate project, this is valid JSON. So why am I getting an error? I thought that maybe it was complaining about extra bytes after the null terminator, so I tried trimming it by making an NSString out of it then turning that back into NSData, but that did not help:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData: [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
```

Because using GCDAsyncSocket is what started this problem, I'm wondering if it has to do with multithreading, but I really cannot think of any reason why that would matter. Any ideas?

P.S. I'm using GCDAsyncSocket because I don't know how to deal with low-level sockets in Objective-C, so my original code had tons of weird bugs.

Comment: Can you duplicate the problem in a simple test project that only does one request at a time?

Comment: I just tried editing the existing one so it would only query one thing from the server and thus receive only one message, and I verified that only one thread was calling it. The problem still occurs. But I should have tried that earlier.

Comment: \0 at the end is garbage. Exactly as it says. JSON doesn't want NUL-terminated data and doesn't accept it. It doesn't allow _any_ control characters after than CR, LF, and TAB. Definitely no NUL byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:
You are probably having a problem somehow with the escape characters. I am no JSON guru myself, but I remember that I once had a JSON string added into an dictionary and then created a JSON from that dictionary. The JSON string itself became escapes, so it would stay a string during parsing. My feeling is you need to remove the escape characters.

Maybe you have some race condition and are writing to the data while the JSONParsing is ongoing. Make sure you are passing NSData and not NSMutableData to the method that does the serialization to make sure.
Remember that NSJSONSerialization is not a streaming JSON parser. It takes an immutable JSON object and serializes that into a Foundation object. If you are adding bytes to the NSData, NSJSONSerialization will see at some point stream of bytes that at that point is not valid JSON (yet).

Comment: It is passing an NSData in. To be extra sure, I tried making the receive delegate function copy the data to an immutable NSData first and checked after the JSON parsing to make sure the data was still the same (it was). I've edited the OP to include the exact bytes of the JSON text, by the way.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because the first paragraph was close enough to my problem, but I've described the exact solution below.

Comment: I can confirm that in my case just calling [myJsonString copy] and using the copy instead fixed the issue. NSJSonSerializer did something bad to my source string (it was called fast 3 times in a serial GCD queue so this might be related)

Answer (score 8):

Strangely, this is what it took! At the start of the didReceiveNetworkData function:

```
//Yes, I know this wastefully allocates RAM, so I'll fix it later.
NSString* string = [[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\0" withString:@""];
data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I removed all '\t' (before entries) and '\0' (at the end of string) characters. Removing just '\0' xor '\t' didn't work; it had to be both. Unless I'm missing something, it seems very strange that NSJSONSerialization cares both about tab characters and trailing null characters!

By the way, cJSON encoded this, so that means that cJSON and NSJSONSerialization do not strictly agree. The online JSON tester agrees with the way cJSON encoded it too.

I might be wrong anyway because this was working before without GCDAsyncSocket (though I still had to remove null characters, as I now recall). Or maybe my old solution was somehow removing the tab characters.

Comment: I have tried this solution. This works fine on simulator but still getting error when I run on my iPhone. The error message is “Garbage at End.”

Comment: Thanks man. I had the same problem for json generated from a C lib.

Answer (score 2):

I also suffered from this problem even though I was requesting the same JSON file twice. I solved it by changing how my iOS app made web requests by a custom retrieve JSON from URL class made by me:

My old way:

```
//init the download JSON class
var downloadJSON = createDownloadJSONObject()

//Downloads and parses the file correctly
downloadJSON.downloadJSON(url: "http://www.example.com/jsonfile.json")

/** waits for the first JSON object to return the json file successfully */

//throws the garbage collection error even though requested file is the same
downloadJSON.downloadJSON(url: "http://www.example.com/jsonfile.json")
```

I can only imagine that the problem came from how I dealt with the cleanup of the objects.

**Working Method:**

```
//init the download JSON class
var downloadJSON = createDownloadJSONObject()

//Downloads and parses the file correctly
downloadJSON.downloadJSON(url: "http://www.example.com/jsonfile.json")

/** waits for the first JSON object to return the json file successfully */

//re instantiate the download JSON class
downloadJSON = createDownloadJSONObject()

//Downloads and parses the file correctly
downloadJSON.downloadJSON(url: "http://www.example.com/jsonfile.json")

//happy days
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a dictionary to store the responses obtained from server .
Each task will have a unique response . So create a dictionary with "keys" as "taskIdentifier" of tasks and "values" as "data".

Eg: 
Inside didReceiveData or any other equivalent methods [where you get response from server ] store response in dictionary with taskIdentifier as keys .

```
 NSString *taskID = [@(dataTask.taskIdentifier) stringValue];
[_task_data_dictionary setObject:data forKey:taskID];
```

Here _task_data_dictionary is the dictionary.In this way you can get rid of the above error .

After this you can get data using the same dictionary using this code

```
 NSData *data = [_task_data_dictionary objectForKey:taskNumber];
```

again using the taskIdentifier .

Hope this helps .