# Result null when convert nsstring to nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have encrypted string from server like this :

> 4gtFiu1DVK2MKGHcFtbuR4spdrhAixptPH0wz2n2VlawBWKlDE/I9m1K4GsBdBH8MJuzhiVHvQy0PYvvcCWuQv6dE1OHzflW3mN3jbEVLrodXvZVnafyo8Lmn6i2x4gGh3XB+ij59FvOOklM+D3E5mhwIFO0cZxGE0eAx2Gn9tj1euoMIChLhnD/FtvuKoucQBCKTTBfihu7dVdZ+gLxqsmusZqUeHnIYYrg3kpH2gu0wQ2GiKm/UMoogYR0JRoYac5ui/aVeDWS14bLoqAc4vJVWVt+vJhJG+a8rC5B68raUDaxhhCJM0b6lpOqAJ/5iVZKLufYMLv2FMNoc5LFkP5QNAYneYCkhfWfNzcDgYC0biYQsT1uIfSgN2q86Qdghe9OBMBFfisfaEsg8+qI7JxhNh+eA6tU5W/yJTIckhvk=

This is my code to decrypt that encrypted string :

```
- (NSString *)decryptAES:(NSString *)text {
NSDictionary *keyDict = [self chooseKey:text];
NSString *key = [keyDict objectForKey:@"key"];
NSData *keyHash = [[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] SHA256Hash];

NSString *newText = [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1) withString:@""];
NSData *encryptData = [NSData base64DataFromString:newText];
NSData *plainData = [encryptData AES256Decrypt:keyHash];
NSString *plain = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return plain;
}
```

I have successfully decrypted that encrypted string into NSString and the result is:

```
{
    "promo": [{
        "status": 1,
        "link": "https://www.s6pay.com/asset_template/img/promo/sspquizpromo.jpg",
        "description": "SSP mengadakan quiz yang berhadiah tiket kereta api dengan menjawab kuis.",
        "promoMessage": "Success",
        "promoTitle": "SSP Promo Quiz! Bagi-bagi Tiket Kereta Api"
    }],
    "count": 1
}
```

I want to convert that decrypt string into NSDictionary/json, my code like this :

```
NSMutableString *plainTemp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[NSData alloc] decryptAES:jsonMutableString]]
NSLog(@"Decrypt %@",plainTemp);
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[plainTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"JSON %@",json);
```

I'm trying to change options with NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves, NSJSONReadingAllowFragments or NSJSONReadingMutableContainers but still give result JSON (null).

I'm trying to check that decrypted string using http://json.parser.online.fr (result of encrypted string) and that result is valid JSON.

What is wrong with my code? Can you please help me? Thank you..

Comment: First check whether you are getting data or not in [NSMutableString stringWithString:[[NSData alloc] decryptAES:jsonMutableString]]

Comment: I have check that NSMutableString *plainTemp using NSLog and that result is : {"promo": [{"status": 1, "link": "https://www.s6pay.com/asset_template/img/promo/sspquizpromo.jpg", "description": "SSP mengadakan quiz yang berhadiah tiket kereta api dengan menjawab kuis.", "promoMessage": "Success", "promoTitle": "SSP Promo Quiz! Bagi-bagi Tiket Kereta Api"}], "count": 1}

Comment: Ohh sorry, I pasted wrong line in previous comment. Please check for data in [plainTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]. Are you able to get data or not. If you getting data then create an object of NSError (say error) & pass the reference in [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[plainTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:& error];

NSLog("Error is : %@",error.localizationString);  In most cases we have to change Encode format

Comment: I getting data when i convert plainTemp to NSData using [plainTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding]. I have create a variabel *err and pass err using [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[plainTemp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&err] but still null, it doesn't show the error

Comment: Use the `error` parameter; that's what it's for.

Comment: the result error using NSLog this Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Comment: OK, so you have your answer.  The encryption/decryption is broken.

Comment: broken? if that decryption is broken why i can get decrypted string from encrypted string?

Comment: Well that is the thing; you *think* you've got an intact string because you cannot see the garbage at the end of the string.  You need to examine the string more closely in the debugger.  The JSON parser is telling you this already.

Comment: OK, but what can i do for fix that problem? when i convert decrypted string to NSData i get 0000 0000 0000 at the end of data, shall i delete that? but when i check decrypted string using http://jsonlint.com it show valid JSON.

Comment: What's the sense of the encryption when you post the private keys on a public website?

Comment: i'm sorry, i just give it if someone try to decrypt that encrypted string

Comment: If there's an actual security concern, please understand that editing your post does not delete the private keys from this website. You can always see it in the edit history. The only way to get (some) security back is to change the keys.

Comment: Just go on google & Search for 'NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 ios' . You will get your solution/

Answer (score 0):

> I have successfully decrypted that encrypted string into NSString and
>   the result is:

Is it true `NSString` object? Why it's so nice formatted? If it's true  `NSString`, you shouldn't have the problems with converting, just use:

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSData *objectData = [sourceString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
```

Otherwise, you should post more details how you decrypt your string.

Comment: i will give you full code to decrypt that encrypted string but this column of comment is not enough so i will edit my question

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 0):

Hello every body i have get answer for my question, i'm using this

```
NSString* string = [[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\0" withString:@""];
data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23321435/5742519 to get answer for my question. Thank you very much for you who answers my question.